# Trouble using recursive calls in C

Tags: c, recursion

I am working on a project that requires me to build a stack of expressions (+, -, /, *, %, variable names), and from that stack, build an expression tree in binary form in parent, right, left order. I've done this project before in Python, and it was rather simple to use recursion to do this but C doesn't seem to want to play along. The reason I want to do this recursively is because like I said, I've done it before and it's the only way I know how. I believe the issue is in the recursive calls because none of the print functions are being printed. I hope I've given enough information for you guys to understand what I am trying to do, and the issue I am facing, thanks!

```
//this builds our stack of expression tokens
ExpNode* buildStack (char expr[]){
   StackNode *stack;
   char *pch;
   int counter = 0;
   pch = strtok(expr, " ");

   //build the stack of tokens
   while (pch != NULL){
      //initialize the stack with the first token
      if (counter == 0){
         stack = makeStackNode(pch, NULL);
         counter = 1;
       }
       pch = strtok(NULL, " " );
       //out of tokens, break out of the loop
       if (pch == NULL){
          break;
       }
       //push the next token onto the stack
       push(&stack, pch);
   }

   ExpNode *node;
   printf("about to build tree\n");
   node = buildExpTreeRec(stack);
   if (node == NULL){
      printf("ITS A NULL");
   }
   else{
      printf("ITS NOT A NULL"); // this line doesn't get printed but it should
   }

   printf("returning the node\n"); // this line doesn't get printed but it should
   return node;
}

//this builds our binary expression tree
ExpNode *buildExpTreeRec(StackNode *stack){
   printf("top of the stack is %s \n", top(stack));
   if (emptyStack(stack) != 0){
      printf("HOUSTON WE HAVE A PROBLEM");
   }
   else{
      char *data = top(stack);
      pop(&stack);
      ExpNode *node;
      printf("Right before we makeExpNode\n");

      //I believe the issue is here
      node = makeExpNode(data, buildExpTreeRec(stack), buildExpTreeRec(stack));
      printf("Right after we makeExpNode\n"); // this line doesn't get printed but it should
      return node;
   }
   printf("About to return a NULL\n");
   return NULL;
}

//this builds our expression node
ExpNode* makeExpNode(char token[], ExpNode* left, ExpNode* right){
   printf("token is : %s\n", token); //this line is never printed but it should
   char * pch;
   int integer;
   pch = strchr(token, '.');
   ExpNode *node = malloc(sizeof(ExpNode));

   //do stuff to make node
   //this function was tested and it works correctly without using recursive calls
   return node;
}
```

Output:

List item

```
a b + // this is user input
Made stack node with a
Made stack node with b
Pushed b onto the stack
Made stack node with +

Pushed + onto the stack
about to build tree
top of the stack is +

Right before we makeExpNode
top of the stack is b
Right before we makeExpNode
top of the stack is a
Right before we makeExpNode
```

The problem lies in the recursive function calls as parameters in the line:

```
node = makeExpNode(data, buildExpTreeRec(stack), buildExpTreeRec(stack));
```

If I change the line to:

```
 node = makeExpNode(data, NULL, NULL);
```

I get the correct output:

```
a //input
Made stack node with a
about to build tree
top of the stack is a
Right before we makeExpNode
token is : a
Done making EXPNODE
Right after we makeExpNode
ITS NOT A NULL
```

Comment: Please show us the desired output as well.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: I commented print lines that should've been printed but never were.

Comment: a general observation: using strtok in a recursive scenario is not good, strtok uses a static buffer that is shared by all calls to strtok

Comment: Does your code terminate normally or crash due to a segmentation fault?  After the output above.

Comment: Terminates normally @MarkHendrickson

Comment: I added what the output should look like, I am fairly certain the issue lies in my passing a recursive function call as an argument.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I added an extra parameter to buildExpTreeRec() to show how the recursion is really happening. My test code passes in "T" where called for the first time and "L" and "R" for the left and right recursive calls.
ExpNode *buildExpTreeRec(StackNode *stack, const char *T_L_R).  C evaluates arguments from right to left.  So the two calls to buildExpTreeRec() in the function call to makeExpNode() is not behaving as you are expecting.

Comment: Mark, that is a clever way to debug this issue, thank you. Is there a correct way to accomplish what I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend pointed out the issue to me, I had no base case in my recursive method.

Fix:

```
ExpNode *buildExpTreeRec(StackNode *stack){
    ExpNode *node;
    char *data = top(stack);
    pop(&stack);
    if (emptyStack(stack) != 0 ){
        node = makeExpNode(data, NULL, NULL); // needed this
    }
    else{
        printf("Right before we makeExpNode\n");
        node = makeExpNode(data,buildExpTreeRec(stack), buildExpTreeRec(stack));
        printf("Right after we makeExpNode\n");
    }
    return node;
}
```